# How can I capture all POST requests call from a client-side-rendering and it request headers programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-crawler, puppeteer

(*Sorry for my bad description if any. I'm willing to describe my problem more specific for you. And sorry because I'm not allowed to post pics to question*.)

I'm trying to crawl products of an E-commerce web page that is created with ReactJS through its API. When I go to a web page follow this URL (https://shopee.vn/%C4%90i%E1%BB%87n-Tho%E1%BA%A1i-Ph%E1%BB%A5-Ki%E1%BB%87n-cat.84) then AJAX requests are made by this web page as you all know.

[Several requests called, I'm trying to get the response from this calling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYB5Z.png)

And now I want to get products got from the `response` of the request above but a field named `if-none-match-` (having a "-" sign at the end) in `request headers` is required, unless nothing will be in response. The value of this field will change whenever `User-agent` or `newest` - params of request is changed.
[This if-none-match- field is required to get data response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbD0I.png)
[Newest params of AJAX call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxUe8.png)

*Note: `newest` params will be changed depending on the page number that I'm currently at. Pic above having `newest:0` because I'm staying at page number **1**. If page number **2** will have `newest:50` due to limitation per page is **50**.*

***So how can I get this `if-none-match-` programmatically?***

*I've tried:* Open devtools with `puppeteer`, searching its generation in `Sources` (devtools), searching for restoring of it in `Cache`, `Local storage` of that web page but no hope.

Any help/suggestions would be very appreciated.